# Terraform provisioner throws key not found error when using private_key

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I have a problem using the provisioner from terraform to execute commands after the AWS machine has been deployed. When using the following configuration I see a key not found exception:

```
...
      provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
          "wget http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-3.2.tgz",
          "tar -xzf apache-jmeter-3.2.tgz",
        ]    
        connection {
                user = "ec2-user"
                private_key = "${path.module}/my-private-key" 
                agent = false 
        }
      }
...
```

How can I use my private key in terraform to execute my commands after machine creation?

Comment: I think you need to use the `file` function there.

Comment: @MattSchuchard What should I do with file? Should I copy the key to the machine first? If I'm not using the provisioner I can also directly use the ssh with the private key. So I don't really get why this step is needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use `file()` interpolation function with `private_key`.

```
   connection {
      . . .
      private_key = "${file("${path.module}/my-private-key")}"
      . . .
  }
```

Look at "Additional arguments" section for private_key, where it mentions `file()` interpolation function to be used with `private_key`:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I see the following error now: jmeter-slaves: is a directory in:

${file(path.module)}/my-private-key
Also key_file is not working anymore with the current terraform version I suppose.

Comment: You have the closing bracket too "soon", which is why you pass into the file() function the folder denoted by "path.module". You have to have the entire thing (folder+file-name) under brackets, like this: "${file("${path.module}/my-private-key")}".

Comment: and you are right, looks like `key_file` is deprecated now.